# About relative Group Homology long exact sequence

Tags: homological-algebra, group-cohomology, spectral-sequences

In this article https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.0071, Jan Essert defines Relative Group Homology $H_*(G,G';M)$ of the groups $G'\leq G$ with coefficients in a $G$-module $M$ as the homology of quotient
$$
\frac{F_{\bullet}(G)\otimes_G M}{F_{\bullet}(G')\otimes_{G'} M}
$$
where $F_{\bullet}(H)$ is the standard resolution of a group H.

But the article didn't say something about the long exact sequence (but mention it in the proof of a version of Lyndon-Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence)

There is another source for relative group homology?.

EDIT: I forget explicit the long exact sequence, I mean
$$
\cdots\to H_n(G',M)\to H_n(G,M)\to H_n(G,G';M)\to H_{n-1}(G',M)\to\cdots
$$
EDIT 2: I don't need the short exact seqeuence...

EDIT 3: I found the answer in this book: Kevin P. Knudson - Homology of Linear Groups, pg. 153. Thank you...

Comment: What long exact sequence do you want? It is impossible to tell from what you wrote what you are asking, really:-)

Comment: Sorry, the classical for relative homology,
$$
\cdots\to H_n(G',M)\to H_n(G,M)\to H_n(G,G';M)\to H_{n-1}(G',M)\to\cdots
$$

Comment: Add that information to the body of the question!

Comment: In any case, there is an short exact sequence $0 \to F(G')\otimes M\to F(G)\otimes M\to\text{the quotient you write above}\to 0$, and the long exact sequence corresponding to that is what you want, no?

Comment: Yes, but this map is injective? I have not clear this...

Comment: F(G)\otimes M is simply a direct sum of copies of M, and F(G')\otimes M is an the abelian subgroup of that that is the sum of some of those copies.

Comment: The tensor products have different base rings, In fact is $0\to F(G')\otimes_H M\to F(G)\otimes_G M\to\cdots$... it doesn't matter?